# remove dashes from a column in a select statment without altering table data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that grabs a list of 'job numbers' from a table. However, the job number displays numbers with a dash in the middle.`(e.g. 645-123)`

How do I select this field and only retrieve the number up to the dash (`e.g.'645'`) and not the `'-123'`?

I do not want the data in the table to be 'replaced' or edited; I just need to select the data but without the dash and remaining digits after the dash.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
select (case when jobnum like '%-%'
             then left(jobnum, charindex('-', jobnum) - 1)
             else jobnum
        end)
```

This will not return an error if there is no hyphen (the reason for the `case`).

Comment: This is removing all numbers after the hypen, but it still includes the hypen. I am getting '6754-'   any ideas. Thanks.